# chart js 2 how to set bar width

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using Chart js version: 2.1.4 and I'm not able to limit the bar width. I found two options on stackoverflow

```
barPercentage: 0.5
```

or

```
categorySpacing: 0
```

but neither of one works with the mentioned version. Is there a way to solve this issue without manually modifying the chart.js core library?

thanks

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You were right : The attribute you have to edit is `barPercentage`.

But maybe the error comes from **where** you edited the value.

As you can see in the [bar chart options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options) :

> *Name* : **barPercentage**
>   - *Type* : Number
>   - *Default* : 0.9
>   - *Description* : Percent (0-1) of the available width each bar should be within the category percentage. 1.0 will take the whole category width and put the bars right next to each other. [Read More](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage)

The attribute is actually stored in `scales.xAxes` ("*Options for xAxes*" table).

So you just have to edit your chart this way :

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.4
        }]
    }
}
```

---

Here is a fully working example with a custom width (`0.2`) for the bar :

```js
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 75, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                // Change here
             barPercentage: 0.2
            }]
        }
    }
});

console.log(myChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

---

## Update (Chart.js Version 2.2.0+)

As stated in the [Release Version 2.2.0 - Candidate 2](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.2.0-rc.2) :

> ### Enhancements
>
> - Can now manually configure the thickness of a bar in a bar chart. Use a new `barThickness` option on the correct axis to set the thickness of a bar.
> - *And so on ...*

Comment: Nowhere in the docs do they say that this option should be put into scale property, so wondering how you knew it...

Comment: @jedi Back then, I used to wander a lot in the chart options via the console or Chrome/FF developer tools to see how charts were made and what possibilities there were - I realised pretty quickly that Chart.js documentation was not satisfying enough for most questions on SO

Comment: Thanks. I am happy to know how exactly you investigate those kind of problems apart from `console.log()`.

Comment: You can add that barPercentage is always included in categoryPercentage : if you want a bar on the full witdh, barPercentage=1 needs categoryPercentage=1 also, otherwise, categoryPercentage=0.9 by default, and your bars will be 90% also.

Comment: Although the documentation tells those options belong to dataset property, not in any axes properties of scales, I find that when putting them in xAxes property using version 2.8.0, it does work, whereas when putting in dataset property, it doesn't. Is the new documentation not accurate for it ?

Comment: @LexSoft In docs page, you can select version number on top. From what I'm reading, usage of maxBarThickness is different between docs 2.8.0 and docs 3.9.1.

Answer (score 36):

For version 2.8+ (and apparently as far back as 2.2), there are now some excellent controls over the bar thickness, max thickness, etc.

Per the [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness), you would set them like so:

```
{
    type: 'bar', // or 'horizontalBar'
    data: ...,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                barThickness: 6,  // number (pixels) or 'flex'
                maxBarThickness: 8 // number (pixels)
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the documentation tells those options belong to dataset property, not in any axes properties of scales, I find that when putting them in xAxes property using version 2.8.0, it does work, whereas when putting in dataset property, it doesn't. Is the new documentation not accurate for it ?

Answer (score 33):

As of v2.7.2 it can be done by:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    maxBarThickness: 100,
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In case if you are using ng2-chart in an angular project then the bar chart configuration looks Alike this:

```
npm install ng2-charts chart.js --save
```

import 'ng2-charts' in your module.

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
```

Now the bar chart configurations:

```
barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
legend: {
  display: false
  },
};

barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
barChartLegend = true;
barChartPlugins = [];

barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
 {
  barThickness: 16,
  barPercentage: 0.5,
  data: [65, 59, 80],
  label: 'Growth'
 },
 {
  barThickness: 16,
  barPercentage: 0.5,
  data: [28, 48, 40],
  label: 'Net'
  }
 ];

barChartColors: Color[] = [
  { backgroundColor: '#24d2b5' },
  { backgroundColor: '#20aee3' },
 ];
```

Now the HTML part:

```
<div class="bar-chart-wrapper">
   <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [colors]="barChartColors" 
     [labels]="barChartLabels"
     [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins" [legend]="barChartLegend"
     [chartType]="barChartType">
   </canvas>
 </div>
```

You can control the height of your chart container

```
  .bar-chart-wrapper {
     height: 310px;
   }
```

Answer (score 15):

`barThickness` and `maxBarThickness` (previously in `ChartOptions[]`) are now a part of `ChartDataSets[]`.

Comment: Although the documentation tells those options belong to dataset property, not in any axes properties of scales, I find that when putting them in xAxes property using version 2.8.0, it does work, whereas when putting in dataset property, it doesn't. Is the new documentation not accurate for it ?

Comment: I'm using version 2.9.3 and this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

As per above answer
Here is complete Bar chart graph using react chartjs2.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
   LinearScale,
   BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const options = {
  responsive: true,
    plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',   // lable position left/right/top/bottom
      labels: {
        boxWidth: 0,     // lable box size
      }
    },
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 1
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      display: false,        // show/ hide x-axis
      grid: {
        display: false      // show/hide grid line in x-axis
      },
    },
    y: {
      display: false,      // same as x-axis
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
};

const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];

export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'datasets',            // label text
      data: [100, 300, 500, 700],      
      backgroundColor: '#7b62ff',   // bar / column color
      barThickness: 6,             // <<<<<<<<<<<<   bar / column size  
    },
  ],
};

export default function ResumesGraph() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Bar
        data={data}
        options={options}
        width={'500px'}
        height={'180px'}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Try this

```
import {Chart} from "chart.js"

Chart.defaults.datasets.bar.maxBarThickness = 73;

//also try barPercentage
```

Comment: this solution worked for me.... Thnx

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested, i made a quick fork **based on 3.9 branch** to manage dynamic width :
https://github.com/stephanebouget/Chart.js/tree/3.9

#### For example :

[image]

#### Live demo

https://codepen.io/stephanebouget/pen/PoerxPP

```
var data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset #1',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    setPercentage: [10, 2, 20, 40, 4, 6, 18], // Here is the magic !!!
  }],
};
```