# Creating categories with different widths in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm creating a line diagram using chart.js, and my X axis is of type category (which, in my case, makes absolute sense). Now, chart.js creates all categories with the same width, which I guess is a reasonable default.

However, I would like to have categories of different width, e.g.: The first category should be 3 times as wide as the second one, and the third one should be 2 times as wide as the second one, essentially rendering something such as:

```
|      |  |    |
|      |  |    |
|      |  |    |
   A     B    C
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397425/1921385 and the [chart.js documentation pertaining to `barthickness`, `categoryPercentage` and `barPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness)

Comment: I took a look at that, and this all refers to diagrams of type bar chart, not line chart. With line chart, I didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using: [`dataset.barPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration)?

I used scale `1.0` to represent `3.0` and made the other ones relative to that scale.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [3, 4, 2],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      barPercentage: [
        1.0,
        0.333,
        0.667
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I need that for a line chart, not for a bar chart, and in line charts IMHO it works differently.

Comment: I need that for a line chart, not for a bar chart, and in line charts IMHO it works differently.

Comment: @GoloRoden Can you provide an example of your "line diagram" in your question?

Comment: Still problem is that categories take equal space. Is there possible proportional distribution with equal spaces between?