# Resize bars' chart in ReactChartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I've been trying to use this library to create a dynamic chart with react:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reactchartjs/react-chart.js

I'm building a horizontal bar chart, but I don't understand how to reduce the height of the rows, this is what I'm getting now:

[image]

Rows are very big and take a lot of space, I tried different options but I couldn't figure it out.

This is the code of the component:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from 'react';
import { HorizontalBar } from '@reactchartjs/react-chart.js';

const Graph = ({
  arrayData,
}) => {
  const data = {
    labels: arrayData.map((obj) => obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Senders',
        data: arrayData.map((obj) => obj[Object.keys(obj)[1]]),
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(213, 232, 255)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(3, 120, 204)',
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };

  const yAxesScaleOptions = [
    {
      barPercentage: 0.9,
      categoryPercentage: 0.8,
    },
  ];

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: yAxesScaleOptions,
    },
  };

  return (
    <HorizontalBar data={data} options={options} />
  );
};

export default Graph;
```

CSS parent div:

```
export const TabPanels = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid ${colorPalette.grey.medium};
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
`;
```

Maybe there is a prop for that but I couldn't find it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a variable that contains these two attributes:

   ```
   const yAxesScaleOptions = [
       {
         barPercentage: 0.9,
         categoryPercentage: 0.8
       }
    ]
   ```
2. In your `options` do:

```
const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }],
    yAxes: yAxesScaleOptions <-- This
  },
};
```

Comment: I updated my code with that but nothing changed, could this problem related to the parent div's css? I updated my answer by adding the css of the wrapper div

Comment: I am not sure. If you check this answer they seem to use my approach too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856729/chart-js-2-how-to-set-bar-width